# I filled MR only in my first name on boarding pass z, problem?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, ana

I filled MR in first name and full name(as passport) in last name when boarding reservation because of no first name and last name in my country .

The name in My Passport is Moe Swe Myint.

But E ticket print as MoeSweMyint/MR MR .

Will this cause me any problems?

Answer (score 1):

Call the airline to check. Shouldn't be an issue so long as your ID matches the name. However if the ID doesn't match you may have a problem with the initial screening.